# Splitting into separate arrays if a condition met JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split up an array of components into individual arrays depending on if there is a `list` breaking the pattern of `heading`, `paragraph` or `hr`. Here is what i have tried:

```
const components = [
  { name: 'heading'  },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'list' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'list' }
];

const richText = [];
const list = [];

  components.forEach((component, index) => {
    switch (component.name) {
      case 'heading': case 'hr': case 'paragraph':
        richText.push(component.name)
        break
      case 'list':
        list.push(`${component.name}-index`)
        break
    }
  })

console.log(richText)
```

Current output is:

```
[
  { name: 'heading'  },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: ‘hr’ },
  { name: 'paragraph' }
]
```

Desired output is:

```
[
  { name: 'heading'  },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' }
],
[
   { name: ‘hr’ },
   { name: 'paragraph' }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering `list` as a break, you can make initialization for `richText` as `[[]]`. You can keep pushing to last `index` of `richText` until a `list` is found. If a `list` is found push an empty array `[]` to your `richText` array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const components = [
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'list' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'list' }
];

const richText = [[]];
const list = [];
components.forEach((component, index) => {
  switch (component.name) {
    case 'heading': case 'hr': case 'paragraph':
      richText[richText.length - 1].push(component);
      break
    case 'list':
      list.push({name: `${component.name}-${richText.length}`})
      index < components.length - 1 ? richText.push([]) : {};
      break
  }
})
console.log(richText);
console.log(list);
```

**Same logic `Array.reduce` implementation**

```js
const components = [
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'list' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'list' }
];

const richText = components.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if(curr.name === 'list' && index < components.length - 1) {
    acc.push([]);
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, [[]]);
console.log(richText);
```

Comment: What about if `components` does not have any `list`? try this one: `const components = [{ name: 'heading' },{ name: 'paragraph' },{ name: 'hr' },{ name: 'heading' }]`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi thats a good catch. I have fixed the issue and updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you :D what if i need to push to another array an Object for each array chunk?


For example:
```
const items = [];

items.push({
   id: curr.name
})
```

Comment: @ray-itm sorry, what do you want to do? i couldnot understand that rom your comment. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```js
const components = [
  { name: 'heading'  },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'heading' },
  { name: 'list' },
  { name: 'hr' },
  { name: 'paragraph' },
  { name: 'list' }
];

let richText = [];
let list = [];

  components.forEach((component, index) => {
    switch (component.name) {
      case 'heading': case 'hr': case 'paragraph':
        richText.push({'name': component.name})
        break
      case 'list':
        list.push(richText);
        richText = [];
        break
    }
  })
  
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function akin to python's [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Given an iterable and a key function, it yields pairs `[key, chunk]` where each `chunk` contains sequential items that have the same `key`:

```
function* groupBy(iter, keyFn) {
    let last = null, buf = []

    for (let item of iter) {
        let key = keyFn(item)

        if (key !== last) {
            if (buf.length)
                yield [last, buf]
            buf = []
        }

        buf.push(item)
        last = key
    }

    yield [last, buf]
}
```

Applied to your problem:

```
for (let [isList, tags] of groupBy(components, c => c.name === 'list'))
    if (isList) ... else ...
```